# Load model from Google Cloud Storage without downloading

Tags: google-cloud-storage, fasttext

Is there a way to serve model from Google Cloud Storage without actually downloading a copy of model? like streaming the data directly?

I'm trying to load a fasttext model that is hosted on Google Cloud Storage. everytime i run the program, it needs to get and download a copy of that model in the bucket.

```
language_model_filename = 'lid.176.bin' // filename in GCS
language_model_local = 'lid.176.bin' // local file name when downloaded
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)
blob = bucket.blob(language_model_filename)
blob.download_to_filename(language_model_local)
language_model = FastText.load_model(language_model_local)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Streaming Tranfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) for that purpose. As explained in the documentation, you can use the third party [boto client library plugin for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-plugin#streaming-transfers).

A streaming download example would look like this:

```
import sys

downloaded_file = 'saved_data_file'
MY_BUCKET = 'my_app_bucket'
object_name = 'data_file'
src_uri = boto.storage_uri(MY_BUCKET + '/' + object_name, 'gs')
src_uri.get_key().get_file(sys.stdout)
```

Comment: how can i use the streamed data to load it? should i load the 'src_uri'?

Comment: Whatever it is that you want to do with the file you have in GCS, you can either download it to you local system, having then that file in you local file system, or just stream the content of the file to have it store in a variable in your code to use it, without actually downloading a file. My best guess is that, is `load_model` requires a file, you will need to have a file, hence, downloading is your best chance. If it accepts the streamed data, then you can pass it as is.